# html code issues template for django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template where this line is written. I know that each form has a primary key when it is saved in the database. But why in this case the primary key is tested to display the title ???

```
<div class="page-header">
    <h1>Backtesting{% if form.instance.pk %}: {{form.instance.title}}
```

Comment: What are you asking? They checked it because that was the logic they wanted to use.

Answer (score 0):

You already answered your question yourself:
This logic detemines if your form data is already saved to the database.
If this is a new form, form.instance is True, but form.instance.pk is False.
If the form instance is a object loaded from db, form.instance.pk is True.

Really basic logic.